# C# Display the same DataGridView in two different Tabs

Tags: c#, winforms

Is it possible to display the very same DataGridView in two different tabs? I could create two different DataGridViews and have a bunch of methods to update them whenever they change to have the same data, but I would rather just have one DataGridView and display it in both places.

Comment: `tabPage1.Controls.Add(dataGridView)` and `tabPage2.Controls.Add(dataGridView)`?

Comment: Note that this is __moving__ the control. A possible solution but it should be noted!! You can move it to and fro when selecting a Tab, or when changing TabPages; the question here is quite unclear!

Answer (score 2):

Rather than dealing with copying the `DataGridView` control, you can set their `.DataSource` property to the same `BindingSource` object. When the tab selected index changed, you'll be able to refresh the controls. Since they have the same binding source, they'll always contain the same data. Example:

```
var bs = new BindingSource();
// populate bs object
dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
dataGridView2.DataSource = bs;
```

Comment: I happen to have a list of objects, can I use this list as BindingSource somehow?

Comment: You can use your list of objects as the data source if you'd like. Alternatively, you can convert into a datatable, but either way it will work.

Comment: How do I populate the BS object? I tried doing this: `tableDataBS = new BindingSource() { DataSource = productList };`, but it seems as though the object is empty/null. (I know for sure that `productList` is not empty.)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use one DataSource or Adapter for your both DataGridViews.